# How do I get the featured image description from my wordpress page?

Tags: php, wordpress

So I set up my wordpress theme to allow users to upload featured images, and Im building my index page to display selected pages' featured images but would also like to display the description of the image.

The thing is, Im not using the loop, Im pulling the page IDs using wordpress's settings API as options.

So displaying the featured images is done like this:

```
<?php $bucket_options = get_option('frontpage_display_options'); ?>
<?php $page_one = $bucket_options['frontpage_bucket_one']; ?>
<?php $page_one = get_post($page_one);  ?>
<?php if (has_post_thumbnail($page_one->ID)) : ?>  
      <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail($page_one->ID, 'bucket'); ?>  
<?php endif; ?>
```

I keep reading that this will work:

```
echo get_post(get_the_post_thumbnail_id($page_one->ID))->post_content;
```

or this:

```
echo get_post(get_the_post_thumbnail($page_one->ID))->post_content;
```

But neither of them displays anything

Comment: Not an answer, but instead of opening and closing PHP mode the entire time you can just open it once and close it once.

Comment: oh I know, I just always see wordpress code like that and assumed that was the best practice. personally it bothers me

Comment: If you see anything in wordpress you have to do the exact opposite if you want to prevent bad practices. True story.

Comment: Not the exact opposite, but here it's save to to follow one's own nose ;)

Comment: `get_post(get_the_post_thumbnail(...))` will never work. What do you want to output here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That capability is awaiting a new release: http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/12235

But a solution that is floating around is to create a function in functions.php:

```
function the_post_thumbnail_caption() {
  global $post;

  $thumbnail_id    = get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID);
  $thumbnail_image = get_posts(array('p' => $thumbnail_id, 'post_type' => 'attachment'));

  if ($thumbnail_image && isset($thumbnail_image[0])) {
    echo '<span>'.$thumbnail_image[0]->post_excerpt.'</span>';
  }
}
```

And then call `the_post_thumbnail_caption();`

Comment: Great, thanks! I modified it a bit to accept a post ID to be passed in since my stuff isnt in a loop but it works perfectly!

Comment: This outputs the caption, not the description. For anyone else who got to this page looking for how to output the description, it's the same way except change "post_excerpt" to "post_content".

Comment: As of this writing this is implemented in the WP core, so you do not have to define the function, just use it as described via `the_post_thumbnail_caption()`.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me. It echo's the title, caption and description of the featured image.

```
<?php
if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) :
the_post_thumbnail();
echo '<p>' . get_post(get_post_thumbnail_id())->post_title . '</p>';
echo '<p>' . get_post(get_post_thumbnail_id())->post_excerpt . '</p>';
echo '<p>' . get_post(get_post_thumbnail_id())->post_content . '</p>';
endif;
?>
```